# Different control is assigned to the same ID after postback - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, updatepanel, asyncpostbackerror

I have recently updated one of my old ASP.NET applications from .NET 2.0 to .NET 4.5 and it was one of the first applications where I attempted to use the `asp:UpdatePanel` control.  It is a survey application where a user can create a survey, assigned multiple question groups to the survey and multiple questions types to each question group.

When I use the page where a user can edit the survey content that contains `AsyncPostBackTrigger` objects that are registered to `LinkButton` asp.net controls in question type user controls registered on the page, I get the following error:

> Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An error
>   has occurred because a control with id
>   'ctl00$PageBody$gvSurveyQuestions$ctl02$ctl03' could not be located or
>   a different control is assigned to the same ID after postback. If the
>   ID is not assigned, explicitly set the ID property of controls that
>   raise postback events to avoid this error.

The user control is dynamically generated based on which control the user selected to be part of the group.  In the `OnRowCommand` event of the `DataGrid` control, it determined which user control to display based on the type of question selected.  Here is a snippet of code:

survey ASPX page:

```
//grid control to allow user to select the question to edit
<asp:GridView ID="gvSurveyQuestions" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
    OnRowCommand="gvSurveyQuestions_OnRowCommand" 
    OnRowEditing="gvSurveyQuestions_OnRowEditing" 
    OnRowDeleting="gvSurveyQuestions_OnRowDeleting" 
    CssClass="com_grid"
    Width="100%" 
    CellPadding="3" 
    CellSpacing="0"
>
    <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link" ShowEditButton="True" ShowDeleteButton="True" 
        ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</asp:GridView>
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="phEditExcellentPoor" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <tr>
        <td width="100%">
            <uc:ExcellentPoor Id="ucEditExcellentPoor" runat="server" EditMode="Edit" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Code Behind of ASPX page:

```
private readonly string m_CreateUpdateQuestionControlName = "lbCreateUpdateQuestion";
private readonly string m_CreateUpdateQuestionText_Edit = "Update Question";

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //here is the code to set the async postback trigger
    AsyncPostBackTrigger apExcellentPoorEdit = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
    apExcellentPoorEdit.ControlID = ucEditExcellentPoor.FindControl(this.m_CreateUpdateQuestionControlName).UniqueID;
    upSurveyQuestions.Triggers.Add(apExcellentPoorEdit);
}
```

Code behind of user control to set link button as postback trigger on the survey ASPX page:

```
public event EventHandler lbCreateUpdateQuestionClick;

protected void lbCreateUpdateQuestion_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.lbCreateUpdateQuestionClick != null)
        this.lbCreateUpdateQuestionClick(sender, e);
}
```

Why I am getting this error and what would be some good suggestions to look where to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> Seems Gridview with multiple CommandField is not working when switched
>   to .Net Framework 4.0. I guess its because of the fact that one cant
>   give an id to command field inside the gridview, so in this case the
>   compiler internally assigns a control id for the first command field
>   and when it encounters the second it assigns the same control id
>   again. So during postback when i try to reload the gridview say when
>   editing a row, it encounters multiple controls with the same id and
>   throws this server error.
>
> I have removed the command fields and instead replaced them with
>   Imagebutton inside TemplateField which has resolved my issue. :)

Courtesy of [This post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1852194.aspx)

Comment: I do have two `asp:GridView` controls on my page that contain `asp:CommandField` columns.  Going to refactor to `asp:ButtonField` to see if that resolves my issue.

Comment: Still getting the same error when replacing the `asp:CommandField` with two `asp:ButtonField` columns in `asp:GridView` control

Comment: I will able to resolve my issue using the answer provided in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18567488/26327

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue by replacing the `asp:CommandField` with `asp:ButtonField` for the Edit and Delete links and renaming the `CommandName` from **Edit** to **Edt** and **Delete** to **Del**

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18567488/26327) helped finally resolve the issue