# Implement GridView edit button without inline editing

Tags: c#, gridview, inline-editing

I have one web form application which has gridview and crud operation.

In gridview I have used OnRowEditing and it sets default textboxes on the selected edit button row. Everything running perfectly fine.

I just have one concern that while click on edit button it sets textboxes on the selected row and I don't want that.

So how to disable auto editing textboxes in gridview while click edit button.

Comment: People can help you better if you post relevant parts of your code.

Comment: @PateeGutee I totally understand your point but as per the company policy I can not share my code over here. So this is all I can share.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001423/how-to-disable-inline-editing-in-gridview).

By changing the CommandName from Edit to edt and from Delete to del, and since then the command events never fired again.